# Powerpoint business promo animation

Tags: powerpoint

before I jump into the whole creating. I would like to know, If It is even possible to make such animation as: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TapiSZDvrRs in powerpoint.

Can It be done in powerpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically speaking, all this is perfectly possible to build in PowerPoint, however, the point is, that at first if you try making it in PowerPoint it won't be that smooth (Although you can work on the smoothness, it can take you hours or even days based on your skill level) and that making it in PowerPoint can be really time consuming. 
Although it's a great idea to put PowerPoint to use, I'll still recommend using Adobe After Effects for this purpose.
In case, you wish to make it on PowerPoint, go ahead. After all, it isn't that tough either. Just make sure you get the timings right. That's the challenge.
Hope That helps